# Trying to add in conditional statements (IF) in formula field

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to add in the condition in the formula field below to include that if Account.Feelings_Today__c is BLANK, but Account.Feelings_Yesterday__c is NOT BLANK, use Account.Feelings_Yesterday__c and I am running into issues as I am not able to call the Yesterday field is the today field is blank for both record types. Any thoughts?

```
IF(
    Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "A_Record_Type",
    IF(
        NOT(ISBLANK(Account.Feelings_Today__c)),
        Account.Feelings_Today__c,
        IF(
            NOT(ISBLANK(Account.Feelings_Yesterday__c)),
            Account.Feelings_Yesterday__c,
            0
        )
    ),
    IF(
        Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "B_Record_Type",
        IF(
            NOT(ISBLANK(Account.Parent.Feelings_Today__c)),
            Account.Parent.Feelings_Today__c,
            IF(
                NOT(ISBLANK(Account.Parent.Feelings_Yesterday__c)),
                Account.Parent.Feelings_Yesterday__c,
                0
            )
        ),
        NULL
    )
)
```

Comment: At a rough glance it looks Ok. What issues are you running into. What are the values for a sample records that is not producing the results you would like and what results does it produce. Ensure when providing the sample that all fields referenced by the formula are identified. That will help get you an answer much quicker

Comment: "...running into issues"? What kind of issues? Won't save? Unexpected output? Computer catches on fire? The more specific you can be, the better we can help you.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm sure everyone might have smiled by reading your comment :p

Comment: @sfdcfox I added it, apologies.

Comment: @RohitMourya I updated the post to minimize your smiles :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`BLANKVALUE` formula](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=0) for this:

```
 BLANKVALUE( Account.Parent.Feelings_Today__c,
            Account.Parent.Feelings_Yesterday__c)
```

But your "issue" is that you are referencing Parent record that can be blank (not populated) - just add a validation for this:

```
IF(
 ISBLANK( Account.Parent ),
 NULL,
 BLANKVALUE( Account.Parent.Feelings_Today__c,
             Account.Parent.Feelings_Yesterday__c)
)
```

I'd modify your formula to look like this:

```
CASE( Account.RecordType.DeveloperName,
 'A_Record_Type', 
  BLANKVALUE( Account.Feelings_Today__c,
              Account.Feelings_Yesterday__c),
 'B_Record_Type',
  IF(
   ISBLANK( Account.Parent ),
   NULL,
   BLANKVALUE( Account.Parent.Feelings_Today__c,
               Account.Parent.Feelings_Yesterday__c)
  ),
 NULL
)
```

And then, if you say your RecordType is used to identify parent/child, you can just use the following formula:

```
IF(
   ISBLANK( Account.Parent ),
   BLANKVALUE( Account.Feelings_Today__c,
               Account.Feelings_Yesterday__c),
   BLANKVALUE( Account.Parent.Feelings_Today__c,
               Account.Parent.Feelings_Yesterday__c)
)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61959/discussion-between-awesome-user2-and-oleksiy).